# How to automatically Sync all my Pycharm projects with Github without clicking any button

Tags: python, github, pycharm

Is there a way for me to Sync pycharm projects between my local machine and Github without clicking any button. That is, Github will act as a backup. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Which platform do you use

Comment: Git is not intended to be an auto-backup. It's main purpose is working on code collaboratively. Your idea would pretty much break that. If you need an instant backup use any cloud storage service. There are many.

Comment: If you really wanted to you could write a small amount of code that uses a file watcher and then commits your changes with a timestamp as a commit message.